# How to get expiration date for a trial license for an app published in the Windows 10 Store using Windows.Services.Store namespace?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I have a [converted Win32 app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) that is posted in the Windows 10 Store under a [trial license](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app). I am using a C++/WRT version of [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app) to retrieve app license info, but for some reason the [ExpirationDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.expirationdate.aspx) member of `IStoreAppLicense` is always returned as `9999-12-31 00:00:00`.

Any idea why?

Here's the full JSON that I'm getting from the Store for my app:

```
{
  "productAddOns":[],
  "productId":"edited-out",
  "skuId":"0011",
  "isActive":true,
  "isTrial":true,
  "isTrialOwnedByThisUser":false,
  "expiration":"9999-12-31 00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Windows Store had a lot of issues with trials including the one you are talking about and also giving away trials for free. I can't say whether it is fixed or not as I gave up on that, just take under consideration that it might be a Store bug.

Comment: @IvanIčin: Thanks for the heads-up. How long have this issue been known for?

Comment: I cannot say if it is the problem now and how long it was active, but one year ago I'm pretty sure it was a problem.

Comment: @IvanIčin: Oh crap! It's still is.